# What the heck are these L-shaped screws and how do I use them to hang my vanity mirror

Tags: walls, screws, mounting, mirror

I ordered a 50-pound mirror from Greece that is supposed to be wall-mounted. It came with no instructions and these things.
[image: the screws and these little plasticy things]

There are holes on the top left and top right corners of the mirror that look like this.

[image: holes, presumably for mounting]
Presumably, the screwy part goes into a stud into the wall, but what are the black things for? Also why are the holes in the mirror so much bigger than the screwL

Comment: In the upper picture is the board under the L-hook and anchors part of the installation kit or part of the mirror? What are those black plastic lined holes for?

Comment: Test how the L-hooks fit into the metal washer lined hole. With the mirror propped up or lying flat on the floor face down, take an L-hook in your hand and see how it fits in past the washer. When the hooks are screwed into the wall you will probably have to angle the top of the mirror in and the bottom out to get it over the L-hooks.

Comment: I would not trust hollow-wall anchors with a 50 lb. mirror.

Answer (score 2):

The black things are wall anchors in case you are not screwing into solid wood, but plasterboard (or holes drilled in concrete.)

The hanger holes are large because the entire end of the "L" goes into the hole, and then the mirror drops down so the "L" holds it until it's lifted up again.

Hopefully obvious that the end of "L" should point up.

Answer (score 1):

Those black things help secure the screws in to drywall.

Drill a hole the size of the black thing into your wall and tap it in to the hole in the wall. Make sure it's snug.

Screw twist the L screw into the black anchor and the black anchor expands to keep the screw in the wall.